# "Id returned 1 exit status" error c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing this fairly simple code but suddenly I start getting this "Id returned 1 exit status error". The most recent change I made to this code was adding all the "endl"s in the display function. I have no idea what to do, please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void getOrder(double&spools, double&stock, double&charge);
void displayOrder(double spools, double stock, double charge);


int main()
{
    double spools;
    double stock;
    double charge;
    getOrder(spools, stock, charge);
    displayOrder(spools, stock, charge);
    system("pause");//come back to these v2v lines
    return 0;   
}

void getOrder(double&spools, double&stock, double&charge)
{
    charge= 0;
    char extra;
    double extraCharge;
    cout<<"How many spools were ordered?:";
    cin>>spools;
    while(spools<1){
        cout<<"Entry must be greater than 1...: ";
        cin>> spools;
    }
    cout<<"How many spools are in stock?:";
    cin>>stock;
    while(stock<0){
        cout<<"Entry must be greater than 0...: ";
        cin>> stock;
    }
    cout<<"Are there any special shipping and handling chsrges?(y for yes, n for no):";
    cin>>extra;
    if(extra=='y'|| extra=='Y'){
        cout<<"Enter the special charge amount:$";
        cin>>extraCharge;
        while(extraCharge<0){
        cout<<"Entry must be greater than 0... :";
        cin>> extraCharge;
        }
    }

    charge=extraCharge;
//no returns needed because reference variables 
}

void displayOrder(double spools, double stock, double charge=10)
{
    double backOrder=spools-stock;
    double spoolsOrdered;
    double subTotal=spools*100;
    double shipping;
    double total=subTotal+charge;
    double ready=stock-spools;

    //spools ready to ship from current stock
    cout<<"There are"<<ready<<"spools ready to be shipped."<<endl;
    //if statement for BACKORDERRRrr
    if(spools>stock)
    {
        backOrder=spools-stock;
        cout<<"There are"<<ready<<"spools ready to be shipped."<<endl;
        cout<<"There are"<<backOrder<<"spools on back order."<<endl;
        cout<<"Subtotal: $"<<subTotal<<endl;
        cout<<"Shipping & Handling charge:$"<<charge<<endl;
        cout<<"The total fee for this transaction is:$"<<total<<endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"There are"<<ready<<"spools ready to be shipped."<<endl;
        cout<<"Subtotal: $"<<subTotal<<endl;
        cout<<"Shipping & Handling charge:$"<<charge<<endl;
        cout<<"The total fee for this transaction is:$"<<total<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: What is your OS and compiler ? It works in my system( g++4.8, ubuntu) after removing system("pause") .

Comment: it says cannot open output file: OUBFIYDWHIBDBD

Comment: It's the linker that is failing. Maybe some problem writing the output file? Maybe you have a prior version open and locked?

Comment: well shnarf, you say it works on yours? i might just take your word for it and turn it in then, im sure it'll work on my professors  xD

Comment: What antivirus? I've had trouble of this kind with Bitdefender due to locking the false positive detection and preventing it from being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code on Dev C++ and it runs perfectly fine.
A probable reason for this error is that the .exe file from the previous run is still ON somewhere. Close it and try again.